# JQ Raw Input of CSV missing first line

Tags: json, csv, jq

It's not clear to me why my output with this template is missing the first line of the data, what am I missing?

Sample: https://jqplay.org/s/6VAJCkLQo9v

Raw Data:

```
watts;2023-02-21T06:50:00+01:00;0
watts;2023-02-21T07:00:00+01:00;1928
watts;2023-02-21T08:00:00+01:00;2686
watts;2023-02-21T09:00:00+01:00;5054
watts;2023-02-21T10:00:00+01:00;7466
watts;2023-02-21T11:00:00+01:00;7797
watts;2023-02-21T12:00:00+01:00;7520
watts;2023-02-21T13:00:00+01:00;6585
watts;2023-02-21T14:00:00+01:00;5084
watts;2023-02-21T15:00:00+01:00;3235
watts;2023-02-21T16:00:00+01:00;1345
watts;2023-02-21T17:00:00+01:00;294
watts;2023-02-21T17:31:00+01:00;0
watts;2023-02-22T06:49:00+01:00;0
watts;2023-02-22T07:00:00+01:00;2637
watts;2023-02-22T08:00:00+01:00;4629
watts;2023-02-22T09:00:00+01:00;6155
watts;2023-02-22T10:00:00+01:00;6639
watts;2023-02-22T11:00:00+01:00;6582
watts;2023-02-22T12:00:00+01:00;6124
watts;2023-02-22T13:00:00+01:00;5135
watts;2023-02-22T14:00:00+01:00;3412
watts;2023-02-22T15:00:00+01:00;1816
watts;2023-02-22T16:00:00+01:00;721
watts;2023-02-22T17:00:00+01:00;189
watts;2023-02-22T17:33:00+01:00;0
watt_hours_period;2023-02-21T06:50:00+01:00;0
watt_hours_period;2023-02-21T07:00:00+01:00;161
watt_hours_period;2023-02-21T08:00:00+01:00;2307
watt_hours_period;2023-02-21T09:00:00+01:00;3870
watt_hours_period;2023-02-21T10:00:00+01:00;6260
watt_hours_period;2023-02-21T11:00:00+01:00;7632
watt_hours_period;2023-02-21T12:00:00+01:00;7659
watt_hours_period;2023-02-21T13:00:00+01:00;7053
watt_hours_period;2023-02-21T14:00:00+01:00;5835
watt_hours_period;2023-02-21T15:00:00+01:00;4160
watt_hours_period;2023-02-21T16:00:00+01:00;2290
watt_hours_period;2023-02-21T17:00:00+01:00;820
watt_hours_period;2023-02-21T17:31:00+01:00;76
watt_hours_period;2023-02-22T06:49:00+01:00;0
watt_hours_period;2023-02-22T07:00:00+01:00;242
watt_hours_period;2023-02-22T08:00:00+01:00;3633
watt_hours_period;2023-02-22T09:00:00+01:00;5392
watt_hours_period;2023-02-22T10:00:00+01:00;6397
watt_hours_period;2023-02-22T11:00:00+01:00;6611
watt_hours_period;2023-02-22T12:00:00+01:00;6353
watt_hours_period;2023-02-22T13:00:00+01:00;5630
watt_hours_period;2023-02-22T14:00:00+01:00;4274
watt_hours_period;2023-02-22T15:00:00+01:00;2614
watt_hours_period;2023-02-22T16:00:00+01:00;1269
watt_hours_period;2023-02-22T17:00:00+01:00;455
watt_hours_period;2023-02-22T17:33:00+01:00;52
watt_hours;2023-02-21T06:50:00+01:00;0
watt_hours;2023-02-21T07:00:00+01:00;161
watt_hours;2023-02-21T08:00:00+01:00;2468
watt_hours;2023-02-21T09:00:00+01:00;6338
watt_hours;2023-02-21T10:00:00+01:00;12598
watt_hours;2023-02-21T11:00:00+01:00;20230
watt_hours;2023-02-21T12:00:00+01:00;27889
watt_hours;2023-02-21T13:00:00+01:00;34942
watt_hours;2023-02-21T14:00:00+01:00;40777
watt_hours;2023-02-21T15:00:00+01:00;44937
watt_hours;2023-02-21T16:00:00+01:00;47227
watt_hours;2023-02-21T17:00:00+01:00;48047
watt_hours;2023-02-21T17:31:00+01:00;48123
watt_hours;2023-02-22T06:49:00+01:00;0
watt_hours;2023-02-22T07:00:00+01:00;242
watt_hours;2023-02-22T08:00:00+01:00;3875
watt_hours;2023-02-22T09:00:00+01:00;9267
watt_hours;2023-02-22T10:00:00+01:00;15664
watt_hours;2023-02-22T11:00:00+01:00;22275
watt_hours;2023-02-22T12:00:00+01:00;28628
watt_hours;2023-02-22T13:00:00+01:00;34258
watt_hours;2023-02-22T14:00:00+01:00;38532
watt_hours;2023-02-22T15:00:00+01:00;41146
watt_hours;2023-02-22T16:00:00+01:00;42415
watt_hours;2023-02-22T17:00:00+01:00;42870
watt_hours;2023-02-22T17:33:00+01:00;42922
watt_hours_day;2023-02-21;48123
watt_hours_day;2023-02-22;42922
```

JQ Template (called with --raw-data flag):

```
{ south: [inputs | split(";") | {label: .[0], date: .[1], values: .[2] | gsub("[\r]"; "") | tonumber } ]  
| group_by(.label) | map({ key: (.[0].label), value: [.[] | {date: .date, values: .values}] }) | from_entries
}
```

If I examine the results, the first entry is missing. I do not understand why. It is not the group_by section or anything because if I remove that it also fails to grab the first line. And it is not in the array later or anything, it is just missing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `-n` or `--null-input` option. (On jqplay.org tick the checkbox reading "Null Input").

This is because the first input is consumed by the context `.`, and any subsequent inputs are consumed either by reiteration to `.` (which happens programmatically), or earlier, if present, by the use of `input` (one) or `inputs` (all). The include the first input into the consumption via `input` or `inputs` you have to sort of prepend `null` as a new first input (which is then consumed by `.`), so all the other ones (beginning with the first "real" input) are left to be consumed by `input` and `inputs`.